# Why am I getting a StackOverflow error in a long method?

Tags: c#, optimization, stack-overflow, jit

I have a small read-only database (based on data from services). The load time is critical so data can't be extracted from DB, XML and so on. I use the direct construction of data in the generated C# file:

```
void Load(){
    var aa = new A[ 100500 ];
    aa[0] = new A( ... );
    ...
    aa[100499] = new A( ... );
    AA = aa;
}
```

There are no recursion here, stackallocks and so on.
But I have got a StackOverflow error.

Looking in Disassembler window I found that JIT converts this code into:

```
    var aa = new A[ 100500 ];
    var a0 = new A( ... );
    aa[0] = a0;
    ...
    var a100499 = new A( ... );
    aa[100499] = a100499;
```

So it create 100500 variables aXXXXX in stack:

```
-- aa[32] = new A( qwerty, asdf );
mov         ecx,185C10h                 -- var a32 = new A
call        001730F4                  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4Ch],eax     -- different for different rows

push        dword ptr ds:[4403528h]     -- a32.ctor( ... )
mov         edx,dword ptr ds:[4403524h]  
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]  
call        00790068                  

push        dword ptr [ebp-4Ch]       -- aa[32] = a32
mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch]  
mov         edx,20h  
call        71CCCD30
```

These changes doesn't help:

```
// 1. explicit variable 
A a;
a = new A( ... );  // a32 = new A(...); a = a32;
aa[32] = a

// 2. limited visibility
{ aa[32] = new A( ... ); } // for each created object
```

This change helps but too ugly:

```
// Works in Release version only
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
static void f32( A[] aa ) 
    => aa[32] = new A( qwerty, asdf );

...
f32( aa );  -- inlined without a32
```

Is any elegant way to remove these stack devourers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you explicitly creating each one of them? Not in a loop? I've never had issues initializing large arrays in loops before. I've initialized over 10 million instances in a loop and never had such behavior. Also, what you have are references, not actual instances, that are flooding the stack.

Comment: Are you saying you've manually populated a method with 100500 individual assignments? I'd have thought that unlikely. If this is code that you've *generated*, why does it matter how pretty it is to read?

Comment: seems that you hardcoded a lot of data into the `Load` method. What is the A class ? You can  read A class list|array from the configuration|resource using the deserialization (from xml, json whatever) just not to have 100499 instances of A created in the `Load` method manually.

Comment: Auto-generated code can cause a variety of issues, there isn't much you can do about the way the C# compiler works.  Just punt the problem and use a large stack.  More than one way to do it, but in this case this code surely ought to run on a thread.  Specify the [maxStackSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread__ctor_System_Threading_ThreadStart_System_Int32_) parameter.

Comment: Probably it makes sense to spend some time and load data from the DB (or deserialize the xml) and cache the result to use later (store the list in the variable instead of executing `Load` several times). You can schedule the data load in background thread when program starts to reduce the loading time on first access. I do not think that splitting one huge `Load` method to several methods is a good idea. The same as hardcoding 100500 class instances in the source code.

Comment: Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack?view=netframework-4.8 can help you?